# Nelson's proof of the inconsistency of arithmetic

Tags: logic, arithmetic, fake-proofs

What are the prerequisites to understand Nelson's attempted proof of the [inconsistency of arithmetic](http://www.thebigquestions.com/nelson.PDF) and the subsequent ["famous" discussion on John Baez's blog](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/09/the_inconsistency_of_arithmeti.html)? I have a reasonable background in mathematical logic (beginning graduate level), but Nelson's outline contains a lot of material/terminology that I'm not familiar with, such as: Hilbert-Ackermann consistency theorem, open theories, relativization schemata, and the BCL theorem. I want to know if it is feasible to learn this background material in (say) 2-3 weeks of study and where I can best start. I think the Nelson "incident" is a fascinating note in modern mathematical history, but there is a lot of other cool stuff out there and I don't want to invest too much time in learning material that will only benefit me in understanding Nelson's "proof" (or are these concepts of more general interest as well?).

I understand this question is somewhat hard to answer precisely, but that is not the point. If someone can put me in the right direction/ballpark I would already be very happy.

Comment: The proof is known to be wrong (http://www.madmath.com/2017/01/the-nelson-tao-case.html). So fortunately you do not need to read it,

Comment: @JCAA That's not really fair - while wrong, it's not uninteresting.

Comment: The result means that there exist many previously unknown natural numbers (since PA is inconsistent). If you find it interesting, go ahead and read it. i find it more of medical interest. But I do not insist, as I said, go ahead and enjoy reading.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, Noah. By the way, JCAA, Tao and Buss themselves found Nelson's work interesting enough to write a postscript to it (in which they explicitly mention the worth of Nelson's work). I don't understand why many people act so dismissive towards Nelson. He was an extremely talented mathematician with many significant contributions, and courageous in his dedication to something most of us believe is impossible (but which still looms for all of us in the background).

Comment: Nash was even more talented than Nelson. Perhaps there is something in the air in Princeton? As I said, read the text, enjoy it.

Comment: I do not think that we can learn much from a wrong proof, but of course, you decide whether you want to read it.

Comment: @Peter It's not just an interesting (historical) fact to learn where Nelson went wrong, or a useful start to try and prove the inconsistency of PRA/PA (which evidently at least Nelson thought to be possible), but it's also about the novel use of methods like Kritchman-Raz. Like I said, Tao and Buss confirm this.... maybe someone can actually comment on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that Nelson's "proof" is very interesting! Indeed, as remarked in [this article](https://webpages.ciencias.ulisboa.pt/%7Efjferreira/RobinsonQ.pdf) (which I linked in another of your questions), we are not alone in this assessment: " Some very nice and unexpected mathematics ensued in the shadow of Nelson’s interpretability program (and related
studies), not only by Nelson himself but also by Robert Solovay, Petr Hajek,
Samuel Buss, Alex Wilkie, Jeff Paris, Pavel Pudlak, Albert Visser and others." (p. 2) If Solovay found it interesting, I think we are in good company.

As for background, it seems clear to me that the first four chapters of Shoenfield, which are also frequently referred to by Nelson, are a good start. In particular, the Hilbert-Ackermann consistency theorem is proved on p. 49ff, open theories are defined on p. 48, etc. Nelson's [Predicative Arithmetic](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enelson/books/pa.pdf) also contains much of the background needed (e.g. he defines a relativization of a formula on p. 5; the schemata of Solovay are probably the ones mentioned on p. 12). Chaitin's theorem is sketched in Boolos, Jeffrey & Burgess's *Computability and Logic* (5ed), chapter 17. As for BLC, I know next to nothing about complexity theory, so I can't be much of help here.

Also, the freely available [Hájek and Pudlák](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421926#toc) also contains most of the needed background, including a crash course on complexity theory (with a definition of polynomial time, etc.). So you may want to study that too.

Comment: I will comment more later, but one quick comment: the thing about Nelson's book is that Wilkie says in his review that he doesn't recommend it to anyone that has no experience working in weak fragments of PA. I'm trying to write a small paper (for a class project) explaining Nelson's failed proof and his general philosophy.

Comment: @Jori Hájek and Pudlák's book is basically about weak fragments of PA, so you may want to check it out. I found it a bit terse, though (and it also presupposes the first four chapters of Shoenfield)

Comment: (Cont...) I feel BCL is not that important to understand Nelson, the Hilbert-Ackermann stuff I can find in Shoenfield (a handy summary is this BSc thesis https://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelors-theses/2015/Emma_Gerritse___4248120___Herbrands_theorem.pdf). Only the schemata of Solovay is a bit of an issue because I can (as you mentioned) only find it in Nelson, and I found it very impenetrable. Nelson gives no motivation either. A secondary source would be very helpful. The Ferreira & Ferreira looks very good! I'm definitely going to read it, because it doesn't seem to presuppose too much.

Comment: I know the Pudlak&Hajek book and I'm definitely going to read it over the next year, but for this small project alone I'm not sure how much it would help to start reading on p.1. There is bound to be a lot of material I don't need.

Comment: Btw, many many thanks for all your answers. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Jori Maybe you should ask a question specifically about Solovay's relativization scheme? Oh, and don't mention it! I also find this stuff fascinating, so I'm happy to help if I can